# On a PostgreSQL 12 / PostGIS 3.0 installation with MacPorts under MacOS, how to use postgis_restore.pl script?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, macports

I have a fresh installation of PostgreSQL 12 / PostGIS 3.0, done with MacPorts under MacOS (Mojave), and I try to restore a PostGIS enabled DB with the traditionnal script postis_restore.pl.

I first created an empty databasen with PostGIS 3.0 enabled on it.
My database dump comes from a PosgtresSQL 9.4 with PostGIS 2.5. It was done with the -Fc format.

I try :

```
perl /opt/local/share/postgresql12/contrib/postgis-3.0/postgis_restore.pl /Users/me/Documents/db/dump_file.dump | psql -h localhost -U postgres target_db 2>errors.txt
```

I get the following answer :

```
Converting /Users/me/Documents/db/dump_file.dump to ASCII on stdout...
Reading list of functions to ignore...
Writing manifest of things to read from dump file...
Writing ASCII to stdout...
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified
Done.
SELECT 8500
DELETE 8500
UPDATE 0
INSERT 0 8500
DROP TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
```

How to solve :

```
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL 12, the behavior of pg_restore was changed to demand either -f or -d.  Previously, if neither was specified then it streamed its output to stdout, which behavior is now obtained by specifying `-f -`.  This was changed because many people were confused by the old behavior (although the change itself is also confusing).

Apparently postgis_restore.pl never got updated to reflect this change.  You should be able to find the spot that calls pg_restore and add `-f -` to it.  Although given the fact that this script is apparently never tested, I'd be cautious about using it without further vetting.

Comment: Exactly, it's reported here: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4605

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot that a dump can have more than a database in it.  Just inform the one you want you want restored, even if your file has only one database in it.  Looking at the pg_restore documentation may help too.

Answer (score 0):

As an updated version of PostGIS 3 seems not to be available in MacPorts at the moment, I corrected the script that way and it solved my issue :

String

```
open( INPUT, "pg_restore -L $manifest $dumpfile
```

replaced by

```
open( INPUT, "pg_restore -f - -L $manifest $dumpfile
```